# How to git clone with username and password in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, git-clone

I am using gitlab . I want to write a .bat file which contains all the steps so that I can automate all the process , which are as follows:

1. open cmd.exe /k
2. git init
3. git clone https://username:password@gitlab.com/board.git  ////// not working
4. git status

---

The 3rd point that is git clone https.... is not working in gitBash anymore. I tried using git clone SSH ... and it  is working which asked for the passphrase and after logging in it was about to clone the repo. As I want to automate the process by providing the login credentials by-default , how can it be achieved using SSH. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean git clone doesn't work (over https with credentials)? What is the console output? The url you posted as an example looks fishy, maybe you used wrong url? `gitlab.com/board.git` should probably be: `gitlab.com/<user or group name>/board.git`

Comment: Yeah !!! It is something like as u said ! I want to use SSH to clone and how to give the passphrase with SSH ??? Can u please help me ???

Comment: Why do you need passphrase for ssh clone? You add your public key in GitLab account settings and you use the private counterpart to clone over ssh.

Comment: Yeah !!! when I do git clone <SSH> then it asks for passphrase . Can u help me how I can insert passphrase in ???  While generating keys I did give a passphrase.

Answer (score 23):

Adding username before gitlab worked for me. It will ask password afterwards.

```
git clone https://user@gitlab.com/project.git
```

Comment: Wow, this is really useful. I didn't have to set up my git config afterward. It worked straight away. No public & private tokens were required either. Just had to log in via a pop-up screen that appeared after entering the command on Windows, and done!

Comment: this worked for me as well :) Such a simple fix.

Answer (score 13):

> While generating keys I did give a passphrase.

Simplest solution would be to generate key without passphrase and use it.

Git clone over https should work but **url from your example looks wrong**. Go to your project page, choose `Clone -> HTTPS` url which should look like

`https://gitlab.com/<username or groupname>/<projectname>.git`

Let's say it is your user's private project and your user would be `Julie`, then url with credentials would be

`https://user:password@gitlab.com/julie/board.git`

**Test url manually** before you start writing your script.

So going to your script example don't init anything just do for https clone:

```sh
git clone https://user:password@gitlab.com/julie/board.git
cd board
git status
```

or if you create **ssh key without passphrase** and set it on GitLab:

```sh
git clone git@gitlab.com:gitlab.com/julie/board.git
cd board
git status
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply , I am told to use with ssh key with passphrase. When I tried 
``` git clone https://gitlab.com/julie/board.git 
Cloning into 'board'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/julie/board.git/'```

Answer (score 12):

You will need to use access token. Gitlab doesn't allow to use password directly.

```
git clone https://<username>:<token>@gitlab.com/group/project.git
```

To create a Gitlab access token:

1. Click your avatar at the top right corner, select `Edit profile`
2. On the left panel, select `Access Tokens`
3. Input the `Token name` and `Expiration date` (if any)
4. Check the `read_repository` checkbox
5. Click `Create personal access token`
6. Remember to save the access token, it appears only once

Comment: Then do we have to enter access token when it asks for password after username while doing `git clone ...` ??

Comment: @Abdullah my `git clone` command contains `<username>` and `<token>`. You should add your corresponding username and token into this command. Git will clone your repository successfully without asking for more information.